# Adjustable Complife Policy

Tags: life-insurance

I am listed as the owner on my policy. Who is allowed to take out a loan against my policy without my signature

Comment: Please elaborate more. For some life insurance, there is an opt-out term that allows the insurer to take a loan from the contributed premium to pay for the late premium.

Comment: Is this a hypothetical, or has someone besides you taken a loan out against a policy that you took out for yourself?